# Magento2 console error locks up browser

Tags: magento2, console

I keep getting this error and don't know how to clear it. Is it a production mode vs developer mode problem?

Please see below:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Unable to process binding "scope: function (){return 'minicart_content' }"
```

Comment: I also have this error Message: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return getTemplate() }"

Comment: What version of 2.x are you using? Did you install from github or download?

Comment: 2.0.2. It was installed via scriptaculous

Comment: Scriptaculous? I think you mean composer?

Comment: Scriptaculopus. One click install via hosting company cPanel.